# React Native without Flow?

Tags: javascript, react-native, flowtype

I just created a React Native project with

```
react-native init MyProject
```

and I am using Visual Studio Code as my IDE. VS Code complains about

```
const App: () => React$Node = () => {
```

with

[image]

> 'types' can only be used in a .ts file.

Some googling tells me that

```
const App: () => React$Node = () => {
```

is not pure JavaScript, but Flow. Is that correct? How can I create a pure JavaScript React project? I am still in the learning phase and want to start with plain JavaScript before switching over to e.g. TypeScript.

Answer (score 2):

you could look into finding an `init` template

```sh
npx react-native init MyApp --template <NAME_OF_TEMPLATE>
```

there is one out there for typescript

```sh
npx react-native init MyApp --template react-native-template-typescript
```

I'm sure, that there might be one for VanillaJS as well